# Implementing IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() in a wrapper dictionary class and wrapper Key struct

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have this struct contained within a

```
public class Class1<TKey1> : IDictionary<TKey1, Class2>
{
    #region Private Fields
    private Dictionary<Key, Class2> _class2Manager = new Dictionary<Key, Class2>(new KeyEqualityComparer());
    #endregion

    #region Key
    protected internal struct Key
    {
        private TKey1 _TKeyValue1;

        public TKey1 TKeyValue
        {
            get { return _TKeyValue1; }
            set { _TKeyValue1 = value; }
        }
        public Key(TKey1 keyValue)
        {
            _TKeyValue1 = keyValue;
        }
        ///Other Key Code
    }
    #endregion
    ///Other Class1 Code
}
```

I am trying to emulate (implement) the dictionary functionality of my `_class2Manager` dictionary  within `class1`.  The trouble arises when I want to implement the [`GetEnumerator()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9eb7a3t(v=vs.100).aspx) method. I am not exactly sure how to convert the `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<Key, Class2>>`  object returned by the `_class2Manager.GetEnumerator()` into a `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey1, Class2>>`

```
IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey1, Class2>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey1, Class2>>.GetEnumerator()
{
    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<Key, Class2>> K = _class2Manager.GetEnumerator();
}
```

How do I convert `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<Key, Class2>>` to `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey1, Class2>>`?

I've thought of [casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828342/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-an-ienumerator-to-a-generic-ienumerator), but I don't think that is the exact thing I need to do to convert it properly.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Any obvious reason to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Why are you wrapping the keys in the first place? I know this is done in Java when you need to change the meaning of `equals` and `hashCode` for the key, but in .NET we have `IEqualityComparer<T>` for that.

Comment: @David  I am only showing a small portion of the code. I wouldn't say that my actual implementation is a reinvention of the wheel. There are other parts to Class1 and Key that I am not showing just so I can show the fundamental issue of my problem.

Comment: @280Z28 I am using IEqualityComparer on the Key struct in a special manner which I implement elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code for you `GetEnumerator()` function, you could try:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Key, Class2>> entry in _MasterFrames)
    yield return new KeyValuePair<Key1, Class2>(entry.Key.TKeyValue, entry.Value);
```

This, basically, will just convert each `Key` to a `Key1` for each entry in the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you!  I will have to look into the yield keyword.

Comment: @MaelstromYamato the `yield` keyword is a very interesting language structure of C# that basically allows you to pause and resume execution inside a function, and return multiple values (in sequence) to a caller. It would be a good idea to look it up, and understand why/how it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to map a sequence of objects from one type to another you can use `Select`:

```
return _class2Manager.Select(pair => 
        new KeyValuePair<Key1, Class2>(pair.Key.TKeyValue, pair.Value))
    .GetEnumerator();
```