# Convert type `System.Collections.IEnumerator` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
// row is a DatGridViewRow object
IEnumerator<DataGridCell> cells = row.Cells.GetEnumerator();
```

I get compile errors specifying that I

> cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.IEnumerator to
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator

and that I need to do an explicit cast. When I try doing that via.

```
IEnumerator<DataGridCell> cells = (IEnumerator<DataGridCell>)row.Cells.GetEnumerator();
```

I get a run-time error.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `.GetEnum().CastTo<DGC>()`

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828342/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-an-ienumerator-to-a-generic-ienumerator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `row.Cells.GetEnumerator()` returns an `IEnumerator` but you are trying to assign it to an `IEnumerator<DataGridViewCell>` which can't be done and you get an exception. Adding `(IEnumerator<DataGridCell>)` in front of it won't help because still it is a different type.

To achieve that use `.Cast` before:

```
IEnumerator<DataGridCell> cells = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().GetEnumerator();
```

IMO a better option is to use `IEnumerable<DataGridCell>`:

```
IEnumerable<DataGridCell> cells = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>();
```

Comment: Downvoter please explain

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but OP said he wants `IEnumerator`, not `IEnumerable`. It's fair to ask him if he's sure that's really what's right for him, but you can't just say "here's something else, good luck".

Comment: @EdPlunkett - Ya :) just saw my mistake and corrected :)

Comment: @Lawrence Vo - Did this help you solve your problem?

Comment: @GiladGreen yes it did, thanks!

Comment: @LawrenceVo - Awesome :) Please consider marking question as solved by this answer

Answer (score 2):

Try using the cast operator first.

```
IEnumerator<DataGridCell> cells = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridCell>().GetEnumerator();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerator<DataGridCell> cells = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridCell>().GetEnumerator();
```

For those following along at home:

```
var able = (IEnumerable)new List<String>();

IEnumerator<String> tor = able.Cast<String>().GetEnumerator();
```

Beats me why OP wants IEnumera**tor** rather than IEnumera**ble** (in fact I suspect he might be better off with the latter), but that's the question he asked.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: @GiladGreen My pleasure!